# Need help with Minecraft Graphics Bug

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing Minecraft on this computer for at least a month and suddenly I start getting graphics glitches. See the pictures in the links to see what I mean

[image]

[image]

My graphics drivers are up to date and I updated java to see if that would help but it didn't.

I just find it strange that this is suddenly started happening. Anybody got any ideas as to what is the cause of this?

Comment: It's really unclear what's wrong in the pictures with that low lighting. Do you see this during daytime as well? Can you post pictures that highlight the issue a little better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to see in your pictures but it looks like either un-rendered surface faces or the lighting bug. In both cases this is just the state of minecraft at this current time. The issues have been lingering and annoying.

If the surface blocks are not rendering but you can see below them and the render when you step on them, you can mitigate this by turning OFF advanced OpenGL. This will not remove the issue but it did help me significantly with my game and a few other people.

If it is that the blocks are just not lit then walk into them, update the chunk some how (place a torch) and it will update the lighting calculations. This is an acknowledged Mojang issue that they are looking at solving with out killing world generation performance.

Another thing to consider are the mods you are running.. Wallhack probably alters the rendering a bit ;)

Comment: Wallhack definitely can't be helping the issue.

Comment: Yep thought as much. Your right about the lighting though because if i break a block it updates. Thanks for your answer, much appreciated

Comment: @manicx Glad it helped, if this is the answer I would appreciate a check mark on it :)